# iOS Safari crashes on Drupal 7 Cart / Checkout pages

Tags: ios, drupal-7, mobile-safari, ubercart

I am maintaining a Drupal 7 website with Ubercart installed. When viewed on iOS Safari, any and all Cart and/or Checkout pages will sporadically and unexpectedly reload and then crash with the infuriatingly vague error "A problem repeatedly occurred on [URL]." This does not occur in any other browser or any other device, and no other information is given, not even a basic error code. I have tried everything possible to nail down what the actual error could be but have had no luck. What I know:

- The website is running Drupal 7.8 and Ubercart 7.x-3.13
- There are no PHP errors or warnings logged at the time of the crash (full PHP logging is turned on)
- There are no HTML/JS errors of any kind in the console at the time of the crash. (I was able to view the phone's console log in real time via my Mac.)
- There are not 2+ elements with `autofocus` or any JS-triggered `.focus()` event on the page, (solutions to similar issues found on this site)

I am completely at a loss as to where to even *begin* debugging this, given the complete lack of any error information of any kind. Where do I begin here? Is there a way to force iOS Safari to cough up what the actual error is?

Comment: What type of request(s) (GET/POST,.. ) and drupal path (node/nid, ..) are involved ? Is there any form on those pages getting reloaded ? It would be easier to debug with a developer console on a desktop browser (maybe safari can emulate ios browser on mac?). I would try to disable/enable ubercart and any other suspicious modules or themes, one at a time, to see if one (and which) is related to this bug, comment out javascript chunks from that module, put breakpoints in some place where you can step into the code before a page is reloaded.

Comment: I have this problem as well but on Drupal 8. I am totally lost there, not even owning Mac makes this error hard to solve / reproduce in the first place. As a temporary solution I removed all "add to cart" buttons and replaced them with custom code pointing to custom-made controller in POST request but this is not how it should be done.

Comment: Unfortunately we never solved this one. No other modules or themes were causing the issue. @EricLavault, as I explained in my post, I am already viewing the full developer console from the phone on my desktop browser. No warnings or errors of any kind. Not many issues where all of StackOverflow couldn't help, but we chalked this one up to a loss.